# How to extend the two classes in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.5

I need to extend the two classes from the same namespace.

for ex:

```
declare namespace myNameSpace{

   class class1{
       ///some methods will be here
    }
    class class3 extends class1{
      //some method wil be here
    }
    class class2 extends myNameSpace. class3 {
       //some methods will be here
    }
    export namespace  class2 {
       //declaration will be here
     }
}
```

i need to extend the 'myNameSpace.class1' class as well as 'class2' namespace.

```
class newClass extends myNameSpace.class1, myNameSpace.class2 {

   constructor() {
    super();
   }
}
```

If i call the both the classes, i got an error message

***classes can only extend a single class***

Is there any other way to fix this issue in typescript.

Comment: You can create interfaces and implement them in your class.

Comment: Please google problem first. The dupe has very similar title and is the first link on page.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any other way to fix this issue in typescript.

TypeScript is single inheritance by design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) but you can't override methods (unless you write a custom `applyMixins` methods)

Using the method:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}
```

You have to implement (on empty way)

```
class NewClass implements myNameSpace.class1, myNameSpace.class2 {
   // empty implementation
   public methodFrom1 : ()=>void;
   public methodFrom2 : ()=>number;
   constructor() {
      // no super()
   }
}
```

now use mixing to actually make it multi extend classes:

```
applyMixins(NewClass, [myNameSpace.class1, myNameSpace.class2]);
```

and now you can create the class

```
const foo = new NewClass()
foo.methodFrom1() // actually calls nameSpace.class1.prototype.methodFrom1
```